# Unrecognized parameter types REMOTE_ADDR and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in .NET Core redirect

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I am trying to convert the following redirect rule that is used on our .NET Framework website to work in the redirect file in the new .NET Core build. I am having no success so far.
Basically the rule does not allow access to specific paths for external IP addresses, but also the rule does allow access to sub paths.
For example: /umbraco/ is redirected to a 404 page but a path like /umbraco/surface/.. is allowed.

Here is an example of the rule in .net framework, which works:

```
<rule name="Restrict Back Office URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^umbraco($|/(?!([Ss]urface|[Aa]pi|[Ww]ebservices|[Pp]lugins|[Aa]pplication)))" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^10\.6\.*.*$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" pattern="^10\.6\.*.*$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}" pattern="^12\.123\.12\.123$" negate="true" />
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
  <!-- Use HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR if your server is behind a load balancer -->
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="/error-404/" />
```

I have read, and added the following code to the startup.cs but this does not solve the problem so far:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.All;
  });

app.UseForwardedHeaders();
```

Any assistance and experience in getting this type of redirect to work in a .NET CORE build would be most appreciated.
Thank you, kind regards

Answer (score -1):

You need to think of a few things.  One Umbraco can now be hosted in Linux, so the Windows IIS rules might not map directly.  What happens if the site is Linux, these rules will not work :(

In vb9 you need to create a middleware, have a look in startup.cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Follow the advice in here to map the rule